# What are the key Syriac pieces of literature?

Tags: book, hebrew

There is very little info on the web about Syriac, but it sounds like it might have some hidden gems. I am looking [here](http://www.tertullian.org/rpearse/oriental/syriac.htm) for the most detailed resource I've found. Wikipedia doesn't offer any insight to what the actual Syriac documents are even *called*, so I can't search for them. What are the names of some important Syriac documents, with a one-liner description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most interesting and most original book in Syriac is the "Dialogue on fate" by a pupil of Bardesan of Edessa (died AD 222). Here it is in a rather old-fashioned translation:

http://www.tertullian.org/fathers/spicilegium_3_bardesan.htm#1

Comment: Curiously, the pious text to which the question is linked does not even mention the "heretic" Bardesan.